# what were the ENIAC's equivalent to the modern CPU's elements?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, decoder, instruction-set

If a  modern CPU contains these elements:

```
- 3 or more register units
- ALU
- control unit
```

and the CPU is connected to a RAM composed of several addresses, what were the equivalents of these components in ENIAC?

ENIAC used:

```
- 20 accumulators formed by decades
- delay lines
- electromechanical switches as a buffer between the electronic components and the input punched cards
- a control of the process
```

How was ENIAC carrying out the fetch-decode-execute cycle? Were the accumulators acting as both CPU's registers and RAM? What was the role of the delay lines?

Comment: Why should there be an equivalent? We can try to draw analogies, but as your literal first sentence says: the above is how "modern CPU" design looks like. And ENIAC is not modern. It doesn't have a "fetch-decode-execute" cycle, as far as I can tell. The idea that RAM and registers are something different doesn't inherently apply to a device that predates both concepts... "What's the exhaust manifold on an ox carriage"

Comment: Delay lines are memory. I don't get any hits on a search for "eniac delay line". Delay lines came into their own with EDVAC, ENIAC's successor.

Comment: It seems like you should probably go find yourself a detailed description of how the ENIAC worked.  This doesn't really fit the scope or mission of an answer here.

Comment: I got some stuff of ENIAC (Goldstine, Haigh etc) but still, I don't get how it was working. It was loading an instruction as a number from an accumulator, then loading the value of another accumulator and send the result to another accumulator. Where was all this information loaded onto?

Comment: ENIAC didn't fetch instructions like a modern CPU or EDSAC. That or Pilot Ace might be a better starting point.